# I want to read 2 YAML files and update the line using awk

Tags: awk

I have 2 files like below. I want to update `whitelistSelectorRegex` under `volumeMonitorConfig` section from one file to another using awk. Is there any best example to use? For example:

File 1:

```yaml
   volumeMonitorConfig:
        maxNumberVolumes           : 5
        whitelistSelectorRegex        : "/opt/xyz"
        blacklistSelectorRegex        : "^/var/lib/docker/.*"
        samplingInterval: 3000   
    networkMonitorConfig:
        maxNumberNetworks            : 5
        whitelistSelectorRegex       : ""
        blacklistSelectorRegex       : "^veth.*|^vnet.*"
```

File 2:

```yaml
volumeMonitorConfig:
        maxNumberVolumes           : 5
        whitelistSelectorRegex        : ""
        blacklistSelectorRegex        : "^/var/lib/docker/.*"
        samplingInterval: 3000   
    networkMonitorConfig:
        maxNumberNetworks            : 5
        whitelistSelectorRegex       : ""
        blacklistSelectorRegex       : "^veth.*|^vnet.*"
```

I want to read from File 1 with selector regex under the volume mount section and update to File 2.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable, textual sample input and expected output and code for us to be able to best help you. Please read [ask], look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples, then try again to ask your question. Also, we shouldn't need scroll bars to read your example or code - make sure to not post more text than is necessary to demonstrate your needs.

Comment: Note: Your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77401934/2) completely invalidated the (previously present) logical YAML structure.

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate structured data (such as YAML), you'd be better off using a parser that can logically interact with that format (rather than manipulating its textual representation, as you would with `sed` or `awk`).

For YAML, [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) could be a choice. It can traverse the document tree to your desired location using the filter `.volumeMonitorConfig.whitelistSelectorRegex`. With `load`, you would then access the contents of another file, and with the `-i` option, you would modify in-place the file provided as argument:

```bash
yq -i '.volumeMonitorConfig.whitelistSelectorRegex =
  load("otherfile.yaml").volumeMonitorConfig.whitelistSelectorRegex
' onefile.yaml
```

Comment: our host will not be having such parser plugin installed. this is not possible using awk.

Comment: @JarugulaSureshChandra `yq` is not a "plugin for `awk`", it's a separate command-line tool. Also, you don't have to install anything if you can't or don't want to, just download and use the [binary](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases).

Comment: Ok, this is not allowed in our systems due to security constrains

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the earlier answer, using Awk for this is extremely brittle and generally a bad idea. But here is a basic attempt which works for your test case (ignoring here that your second YAML structure is invalid).

```
awk '/volumeMonitorConfig:/ { in_vol=1; indent="" }
    in_vol && !/volumeMonitorConfig:/ && !indent { indent=$0; sub(/[^ ].*/, "", indent) }
    in_vol && !($0 ~ "^" indent) { in_vol=0 }
    NR==FNR && in_vol && /whitelistSelectorRegex/ { volstr=$0 }
    NR > FNR && in_vol && /whitelistSelectorRegex/ { print volstr; next }
    NR > FNR' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

This blindly copies the line with `whitelistSelectorRegex` from the section in the first file, and plonks it into place in the second. We rely on the `volumeMonitorConfig:` line to figure out when we are in the right region, and for the indentation from the captured line to no longer match the current block to tell us when we are out of the region. If there is no match, this will fail in slightly peculiar ways.

Demo: https://ideone.com/2xVoiu

Awk is not a complex language; read an intro and the detailed syntax here should be abundantly obvious for the most part. The hack to figure out when the indentation no longer matches is perhaps a bit beyond the introductory course but not hard to make sense of.

Comment: How to ignore commented lines say *# whiteSelectorRegex"

Comment: Did you try to read a brief introduction to Awk? Skip lines which match that regex; probably `/^ *#/ { next }` or something different, depending on whether you want to remove them entirely or just ignore them while matching.

Comment: I am just going through it..  I just need to ignore them

Comment: So probably `NR==FNR && in_vol && /whitelistSelectorRegex/ && !/^ *#/ { volstr=$0 }` and perhaps elsewhere. You have provided no examples; ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements if you need more help.